# How many words are there in Tanach?

Tags: words, number, tanach, aleph-bet-letters, statistics

How many **letters** are in the Torah?

How many **words** are in the Torah?

How many **verses** are in the Torah?

How many **chapters** are in the Torah?

How many letters, words, verses, and chapters are in every sefer of the Torah?

How many letters are in the Tanach?

How many words are in the Tanach?

How many verses are in the Tanach?

How many chapters are in the Tanach?

How many letters, words, verses, and chapters are in every sefer of the Tanach?

I just want to get a sense of the size, and to compare it with other texts.

Comment: Which version of the Torah?

Comment: this for the torah http://www.aishdas.org/toratemet/en_pamphlet9.html

Comment: Of note is the Gemara in Kiddushin 30a. Though not a single statistic mentioned there is accurate.

Comment: Note that chapters are a christian addition and do not necessarily follow any Jewish divisions. for example, chapter two in Bereishis starts with shabbat, while the mesorah puts it at the end of the six days of creation (chapter 1)

Answer (score 13):

There are 304,805 letters in the Torah.

There are 79,976 words in the Torah.

There are 5,888 or 5,845 verses in the Torah.

Bereishit (Genesis)

- 12 Sidrot
- 50 Chapters
- 1,534 Verses

Shmot (Exodus)

- 11 Sidrot
- 40 Chapter
- 1,209 Verses

Vayikra (Leviticus)

- 10 Sidrot
- 27 Chapters
- 859  Verses

Bamidbar (Numbers)

- 10 Sidrot
- 36 Chapters
- 1,288 Verses

Devarim (Deuteronomy)

- 11 Sidrot
- 34 Chapters
- 955  Verses

Sources:

http://www.torahtots.com/torah/tanach_facts.htm. http://www.aishdas.org/toratemet/en_pamphlet9.html

Comment: This is a community wiki, add on the answers I did not add.

Comment: How do you know this? Which version of the text are you using?

Comment: @DoubleAA the sites which I am using for a source does not say which one they counted from.

Comment: What do you mean by "5888 or 5845 verses"?

Comment: If you look in the links. one site says 5888 and one 5845

Comment: Like I said, I got these numbers from the links (in the case of letters http://www.torahtots.com/torah/tanach_facts.htm) I do not know if they included kri / ktiv conflicts.

Comment: You give two different total counts for the number of verses, but only one count for each book, so there's no explanation of where the discrepancy comes from.

Comment: @TRiG If you clicked the links you will see Torah Tots gives the whole torah count and each sefer count but aishdas only gives the whole torah count

Comment: 5888 is what the talmud in kiddushin 30a, counts as verses in the 5 books, , 5845 is apparently what we have according to this etzion.org.il link. And according to that gemara in kiddushin 30a, the psalms is almost as long as the sefer torah. `http://etzion.org.il/en/shiur-7c-nusach-ha-mikra-%E2%80%93-a‌​ccuracy-biblical-tex‌​t `

Comment: Also  he asked re tanach and have only answered regarding the first 5 books

Answer (score 4):

**How many letters, words, verses and chapters are in the Torah?**

According to [Even-Shoshan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Even-Shoshan)'s [קונקורדנציה חדשה לתנ"ך](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/63508/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%9A---%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9F) :

[image]

Note: [Kidushim 30a](http://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.30a?lang=en) mention that there are 5.888 verses in torah.

**How many words are in the [Tanach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanakh)?**

- Torah: 79,847 words (according to E.S.)
- Neviim: 141,414 words (also, according to E. S.)
- Kesuvim: 83,640 words (according to [Spelling in the Hebrew Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8876533427) by Francis I. Anderson.
  Total = 304,901 words in Tanach.

**How many verses are in the Tanach?**

8,064 verses, according to Francis I. Anderson's book above.

**How many chapters are in the Tanach?**

[This site](http://www.torahtots.com/torah/tanach_facts.htm) has the quantity of perakim in every sefer of the Tanach.

Comment: Interesting to note how close the number of verses in Tanach is to the number of letters in Chumash.  Not sure what to do with that connection through.

Answer (score 0):

According to our Open-Source [Program](https://github.com/TorahBibleCodes/TorahBibleCodes/blob/master/D.py), there are 5846 verses in Torah.

Genesis:
1533 Verses

Exodus:
1210 Verses

Leviticus:
859 Verses

Numbers:
1288 Verses

Deuteronomy:
956 Verses

According to our calculations of the data, there are exactly 304,853 letters in the Torah.

Comment: This answer would be a great deal more compelling if you'd [edit] in some more information about what your program uses as source data and any methods it uses for counting verses.

Comment: Glad to know that that python code exists. Any idea where the one verse discrepancy comes from?

Comment: I explained more about the program in my initial answer, and I shared a separate post about the program to let people know, but that post got erased, and this answer got edited.  You can read about the program in detail since it is open-source available to all.  You can see that the texts are from the Sefaria.org Hebrew texts, and you if know a bit of python, you can take the dictionary of verses created, i.e. "D", and perform some python dictionary operations, e.g. "len(D)" which gives you the verse/entry count = 5846 verses according to Masoretic Text order which is slightly diff than KJV.

Comment: Great, then edit in that you use the text of Sefaria!

Comment: All details are included in our GitHub including forks to the Sefaria open-source texts in public domain.

Comment: Sefaria uses the Leningrad Codex which differs in many spellings from traditional texts. This number is misleading.

Comment: Our program should work the same with whatever version of Torah texts provided in JSON format.  It scales well and works at a fundamental level to import whatever texts are provided (e.g. here Sefaria texts in JSON), and interactive data objects are created from the data provided.  If you have more accurate other texts to provide in JSON format, we will be pleased to also use your texts in our scientific tests.