# How many letters are there in Tanach?

Tags: tanach, aleph-bet-letters, pentateuch-chumash, navi-prophets, ketuvim

Although I know how many letters there are in the five books of the Torah, 304,805, I do not know how many letters there are in Neviim and Kesuvim.

So, my question is, "How many letters are there in Tanach?"

Comment: Is this in a Temani Torah or a Sefardi Torah?

Comment: , חסרות ויתרות?

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer, because even different Masoretic codices may have different numbers of characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many words are there in Tanach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44230/how-many-words-are-there-in-tanach) While the title asks just about the words, the body clearly specifies letters as well.

Comment: @DonielF Fair cop

Comment: @JoshuaPearl ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question after a long time of copying and pasting.

In Tanach, there are 1,196,824 letters. This does not include Kri, but only the Ksiv. It includes the 9 inverted nuns.

Comment: Which version of Tanach is this based on?

Comment: @DoubleAA Mechon Mamre