# What is the total number of Pesukim in Tanach?

Tags: tanach, statistics

What is the total number of Pesukim in Tanach?

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62455/what-is-the-total-amount-and-count-of-pesukim-in-the-torah) addresses the Torah, but I have yet to find an answer for Tanach (at least, in the Jewish tradition - the answer for Christians is easily Googlible.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many words are there in Tanach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44230/how-many-words-are-there-in-tanach), which asks about verses as well.

Comment: IINM it's 23204

Comment: does this help http://www.torahtots.com/torah/tanach_facts.htm

Comment: If you have the time, you can download the full text of Tanach from Sefaria or some other website, throw it into a text editor, count the lines starting with a single letter or whatever indicates a line with a pasuk.

Comment: @rosends You should put the count shown in the link that you gave as an answer. Note that the total number of pesukim given at that link is 22,098